# Effects of an electrode in a microchannel flow

Tags: models, electrochemistry, osmosis

I am working on modeling the effects of an electrode in a microchannel flow. I am a little confused about how to model this.

I have two electrodes on the boundary. Do I add the electric field effects in the velocity boundary conditions or in the momentum equation as an external force term. I have seen both cases in the literature.

How will it make the difference if i add the electric field term in the boundary or in the bulk flow or both?

Also, I am a little confused about how to calculate my electric field vector in this case.

Can anyone please explain so i dont get lost or make a mistake?